# IEEE bibliography stops at \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using `Miktex` with `WinEdt editor` for writing IEEE conference artile. I copied `IEEEabrv` and `IEEEtran` file to my article `LaTeX` folder and used this code. (`Bib_ref` is my bibliography file)

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bib_ref}


\end{thebibliography}
```

Wen I run my `LaTeX` file, The console stops at `\end{thebibliography}` and I have this error :

```
LateX Error: Something's wrong-perhaps a missing \item.
```

There is one bibliography from google scholar that I inserted to my bib file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You *mustn't* have the `thebibliography` environment if you use `\bibliography`, because BibTeX will automatically supply it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To insert references, you may use **either** `thebibliography` environment (to list entries manually) or `\bibliography` (to include an external BibTeX file). Since you are using the latter way, there is no need to wrap `\bibliography` inside a `thebibliography` environment. This should work:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
% main body ...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bib_ref}
\end{document}
```